# GeoServer failed to start on Tomcat 8.0.24

Tags: geoserver, java, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get GeoServer up and running on an Amazon EC2 instance but it does not work. I am using Java 8 (Oracle) and Tomcat 8.0.24. The thing is I have got the same stack up and running on a local VM but does not work on the EC2.

Here is the Tomcat log:

```
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.027 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.029 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 1 2015 20:19:55 UTC
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.029 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.24.0
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.029 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.029 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.13.0-48-generic
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.029 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b14
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.031 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /var/local/tomcat8
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.031 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /var/local/tomcat8
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.031 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/local/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/var/local/tomcat8/endorsed
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/local/tomcat8
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/var/local/tomcat8
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/local/tomcat8/temp
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.269 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.294 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.299 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.300 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 947 ms
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.348 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.350 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
24-Jul-2015 04:06:12.394 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver.war
24-Jul-2015 04:06:18.477 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Jul-2015 04:06:19.315 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Extension lookup 'XStreamPersisterInitializer', but ApplicationContext is unset.
24-Jul-2015 04:06:20.972 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Extension lookup 'GeoServerSecurityProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.169 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.184 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/geoserver] startup failed due to previous errors
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.194 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Beginning GeoServer cleanup sequence
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.194 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Unregistered JDBC driver org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver@2967ee6f
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.194 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Unregistered JDBC driver org.h2.Driver@7c9a7a33
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.194 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Unregistered JDBC driver org.postgresql.Driver@10560f58
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.214 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory GeoserverWKTOperationFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
  COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY = PropertyCoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
    CRS_FACTORY                          = ReferencingObjectFactory                                                      
    CS_FACTORY                           = (same as CRS_FACTORY)                                                         
    DATUM_FACTORY                        = DatumAliases                                                                  
    MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY               = DefaultMathTransformFactory                                                   

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.216 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory LongitudeFirstFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER           = true                                                          
  FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS             = false                                                         
  FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS                  = false                                                         
  CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                       = OrderedAxisAuthorityFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
    DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]    
      EPSG_DATA_SOURCE                       = java:comp/env/jdbc/EPSG                                       
      DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                = FactoryUsingHSQL["European Petroleum Survey Group"]           
        FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER     = false                                                         
        FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS       = false                                                         
        FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS            = false                                                         
        VERSION                              = 8.6                                                           
        CRS_FACTORY                          = ReferencingObjectFactory                                      
        CS_FACTORY                           = (same as CRS_FACTORY)                                         
        DATUM_FACTORY                        = DatumAliases                                                  
        MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY               = DefaultMathTransformFactory                                   
      CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
      CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
      COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                     = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                    = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS                = false                                                         
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS           = false                                                         
    FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER         = true                                                          
  CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                      = (same as CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                                

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.221 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory HTTP_AuthorityFactory["URL in OGC namespace"]
  DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                = AllAuthoritiesFactory["All"]     
  CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
  CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
  COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.339 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory GeoserverOverridingWKTFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
  CRS_AUTHORITY_EXTRA_DIRECTORY    = null                                                       
  DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY          = PropertyAuthorityFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS = false                                                      
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS      = false                                                      
    CRS_FACTORY                    = ReferencingObjectFactory                                   
    CS_FACTORY                     = (same as CRS_FACTORY)                                      
    DATUM_FACTORY                  = DatumAliases                                               
    MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY         = DefaultMathTransformFactory                                
  CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY             = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                          
  CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY            = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                          

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory LongitudeFirstFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER           = true                                                          
  FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS             = false                                                         
  FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS                  = false                                                         
  CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                       = OrderedAxisAuthorityFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
    DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]    
      EPSG_DATA_SOURCE                       = java:comp/env/jdbc/EPSG                                       
      DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                = FactoryUsingHSQL["European Petroleum Survey Group"]           
        FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER     = false                                                         
        FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS       = false                                                         
        FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS            = false                                                         
        VERSION                              = 8.6                                                           
        CRS_FACTORY                          = ReferencingObjectFactory                                      
        CS_FACTORY                           = (same as CRS_FACTORY)                                         
        DATUM_FACTORY                        = DatumAliases                                                  
        MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY               = DefaultMathTransformFactory                                   
      CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
      CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
      COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                     = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                    = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS                = false                                                         
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS           = false                                                         
    FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER         = true                                                          
  CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                      = (same as CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                                

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.346 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory GeoserverCustomWKTFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
  CRS_AUTHORITY_EXTRA_DIRECTORY    = null                                                       
  DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY          = PropertyAuthorityFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS = false                                                      
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS      = false                                                      
    CRS_FACTORY                    = ReferencingObjectFactory                                   
    CS_FACTORY                     = (same as CRS_FACTORY)                                      
    DATUM_FACTORY                  = DatumAliases                                               
    MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY         = DefaultMathTransformFactory                                
  CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY             = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                          
  CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY            = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                          

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.354 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory CartesianAuthorityFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
  CRS_FACTORY            = ReferencingObjectFactory   
  CS_FACTORY             = (same as CRS_FACTORY)      
  DATUM_FACTORY          = DatumAliases               
  MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY = DefaultMathTransformFactory

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.354 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory HTTP_AuthorityFactory["URL in OGC namespace"]
  DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                = AllAuthoritiesFactory["All"]     
  CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
  CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
  COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.355 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory AutoCRSFactory["Automatic Projections"]
  CRS_FACTORY            = ReferencingObjectFactory   
  CS_FACTORY             = (same as CRS_FACTORY)      
  DATUM_FACTORY          = DatumAliases               
  MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY = DefaultMathTransformFactory

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.355 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory WebCRSFactory["Web Map Service CRS"]
  CRS_FACTORY            = ReferencingObjectFactory   
  CS_FACTORY             = (same as CRS_FACTORY)      
  DATUM_FACTORY          = DatumAliases               
  MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY = DefaultMathTransformFactory

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.445 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory LongitudeFirstFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER           = true                                                          
  FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS             = false                                                         
  FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS                  = false                                                         
  CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                       = OrderedAxisAuthorityFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]
    DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory["European Petroleum Survey Group"]    
      EPSG_DATA_SOURCE                       = java:comp/env/jdbc/EPSG                                       
      DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                = FactoryUsingHSQL["European Petroleum Survey Group"]           
        FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER     = false                                                         
        FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS       = false                                                         
        FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS            = false                                                         
        VERSION                              = 8.6                                                           
        CRS_FACTORY                          = ReferencingObjectFactory                                      
        CS_FACTORY                           = (same as CRS_FACTORY)                                         
        DATUM_FACTORY                        = DatumAliases                                                  
        MATH_TRANSFORM_FACTORY               = DefaultMathTransformFactory                                   
      CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
      CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
      COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                     = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                    = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                             
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_UNITS                = false                                                         
    FORCE_STANDARD_AXIS_DIRECTIONS           = false                                                         
    FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER         = true                                                          
  CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                      = (same as CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)                                

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.453 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Disposing referencing factory HTTP_AuthorityFactory["URL in OGC namespace"]
  DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                = AllAuthoritiesFactory["All"]     
  CS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                   = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
  CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY                  = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
  COORDINATE_OPERATION_AUTHORITY_FACTORY = (same as DATUM_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)

24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.454 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Shut down GT referencing threads 
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.454 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Shut down GT  SPI 
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.454 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Shut down coverage thread pool 
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.457 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@1673f12e]) and a value of type [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl] (value [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.471 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] null.null Prefs file removed in background /root/.java/.userPrefs/org/geotools/referencing/wkt/prefs.xml
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.476 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@81d0795]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.TransverseMercator.Provider] (value [PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.486 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver.war has finished in 15,092 ms
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.487 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.557 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 69 ms
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.557 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/target
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.583 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/target has finished in 26 ms
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.584 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/examples
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.820 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/examples has finished in 236 ms
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.820 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/host-manager
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.855 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/host-manager has finished in 35 ms
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.856 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/manager
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.884 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/manager has finished in 29 ms
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.885 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/docs
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.907 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/tomcat8/webapps/docs has finished in 22 ms
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.913 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.924 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Jul-2015 04:06:27.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 15624 ms
```

Comment: which version of tomcat are you using - there is a known issue with 8.0.24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @iant, you are right, Tomcat 8.0.24 has apparently some issues. I just tested it with Tomcat 8.0.20 and it worked fine. So now I have GeoServer up and running on Tomcat 8.0.22 using Java 8 (Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

Which AMI are you using? I have successfully installed GeoServer using Ubuntu 14.04 with Tomcat7 many times. [This tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Java/tutorial/Tomcat7_Ubuntu_14_Install_On_Amazon_EC2.php) helped me when I was starting out. Installing GeoServer is simple after you get Tomcat and the web interface properly installed. The only other thing you need to do is change tomcat's default file size which is a bit too small for GeoServer. This configuration file lives at /usr/share/tomcat7-admin/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml and you need to change the max file size to 62914560 MBytes.

Comment: The problem was using the tomcat 8.0.24, as @ian mentioned in the comment above. I could get GeoServer up and running with tomcat 8.0.22.